# Xpages: make tables with all fixed cells but last

Tags: xpages, html-table

I am having trouble understanding why I cannot control tables in Xpages in general and in HTML in particular.

I want some cells to have a fixed-width. For example, my first column in the table I am working on is a checkbox, so there is zero reason the width should ever change. The second column has two images that can be different but the width is always going to be the same. I HATE it when the size of these columns moves all around, as it looks bad.

Ideally I would like to be able to specify which cells are fixed and which are resizable, but if I cannot do that I want a table with every cell fixed except the last one.

Any suggestion on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

David is correct, I should have added code. I am doing so now.

The code below is a repeat that generally dos what I want it to do. I am very happy for any suggestions to improve it or make it more flexible.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view
    xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
    <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoView
            var="view1"
            viewName="(xpAllPCBuilds)" />
    </xp:this.data>
    <xp:this.resources>
        <xp:styleSheet
            href="/custom.css" />
    </xp:this.resources>
    <xe:firebugLite
        id="firebugLite1" />
    <xe:widgetContainer
        id="widgetContainerView"
        style="width:99.00%">
        <xp:panel>
            <xp:repeat
                id="repeat1"
                var="rowData"
                indexVar="repeatIndex"
                value="#{view1}">
                <xp:this.facets>
                    <xp:text
                        disableTheme="true"
                        xp:key="header"
                        escape="false">
                        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[<table class='lotusTable repeatRowColors' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
<tr class ='lotusFirst lotusSort scope='col'>
<th>Employee Name</th>
<th>Computer</th>
<th>Create Date</th>
<th>Create User</th>
<th>ID</th>

</tr>
</thead>]]>
                        </xp:this.value>
                    </xp:text>
                    <xp:text
                        disableTheme="true"
                        xp:key="footer"
                        escape="false">
                        <xp:this.value>
                            <![CDATA[</table>]]></xp:this.value>
                    </xp:text>
                </xp:this.facets>
                <xp:this.rows><![CDATA[#{javascript:var rows:Integere = viewScope.get("rows");
if (rows == null)
{return 5}
else
{return rows}}]]></xp:this.rows>
                <xp:tr
                    id="rowDataContainer">
                    <xp:td
                        style="width:200px;min-width:200px;max-width: 200pxx">
                        <xp:link
                            escape="true"
                            id="link1"
                            value="">
                            <xp:this.text><![CDATA[#{javascript:rowData.getColumnValue("employeeName")}]]></xp:this.text>
                            <xp:eventHandler
                                event="onclick"
                                submit="true"
                                refreshMode="complete">
                                <xp:this.action>
                                    <xp:openPage
                                        name="xpFormPCBuild.xsp"
                                        target="openDocument">
                                        <xp:this.documentId><![CDATA[#{javascript:rowData.getDocument().getUniversalID()}]]></xp:this.documentId>
                                    </xp:openPage>
                                </xp:this.action>
                            </xp:eventHandler>
                        </xp:link>
                    </xp:td>
                    <xp:td
                        style="width:50px;min-width:50px;max-width: 50px">
                        <xp:text
                            escape="true"
                            id="computedField2">
                            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:rowData.getColumnValue("computerName");}]]>
                            </xp:this.value>
                        </xp:text>
                    </xp:td>
                    <xp:td
                        style="width:75px;min-width:75px;max-width: 75px">
                        <xp:text
                            escape="true"
                            id="computedField3">
                            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:rowData.getColumnValue("CrtDte");}]]>
                            </xp:this.value>
                        </xp:text>
                    </xp:td>
                    <xp:td
                        style="width:200px;min-width:200px;max-width: 200px">
                        <xp:text
                            escape="true"
                            id="computedField4">
                            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:rowData.getColumnValue("crtUsr");}]]>
                            </xp:this.value>
                        </xp:text>
                    </xp:td>
                    <xp:td>
                        <xp:text
                            escape="true"
                            id="computedField5">
                            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:rowData.getColumnValue("ID")}]]></xp:this.value>
                        </xp:text>
                    </xp:td>
                </xp:tr>
            </xp:repeat>
        </xp:panel>
    </xe:widgetContainer>
</xp:view>
```

Comment: Bryan - you really need to post code samples for questions like this.  There was a similar question the other day. Don't remember if that was you or not.  But the jist was that the repeat control needs to build the table header/footer as well as the body

Comment: David, my apologies, I was in a hurry and didn't post the code. I have done so now. I have posted what I think is a decent solution to this problem. I do have a few other outstanding questions, I will post my answers. I have been overwhelmed this past week.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using xp:table you can insert some HTML inside the xp:table container:
a colgroup (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_colgroup.asp). With that you can control your column widhts with CSS e.g. `style="width:200px"`

Comment: Oliver, thank you for your answer. I don't think that I quite get colgroups yet; I am going to work with this some more. But I do think I have something that seems to work - pasting the code back into the original question. I have a feeling column group could make this more concise. If so please suggest how. I would be very interested to know.